# Why when subtracting datetime in R with grouped data, the results are in minutes rather than seconds?

Tags: r, dplyr, time

I had thought when subtracting two POSIXct variables that the result would be seconds. However, I have found the situation when my data is grouped that it gives me the result in minutes rather than seconds. Why would that be?

Comment: Use `difftime` instead of just using `-` as `difftime`, you can specify `units="sec"` or `"min"`. The issue with using `-` is that when the time difference is less than a min, it may return in 'sec'

Comment: I am sometimes using naive variables that don't work with difftime. Trying to not have to switch my code around all the time based on the variable type, but I guess I'll have to. Ahhh, ok, thank you for that extra info about the minus. Darn. Wonder how to subtract naive time....... that was my work around.

Comment: Not clear what you meant by `naive` variables.  Your description in the question was `when subtracting two POSIXct variables`

Comment: If you meant naive time i.e. `str1 <- "02:15:24"; str2 <- "03:15:28"` convert to ITime i.e. `difftime(as.ITime(str1), as.ITime(str2), units = "secs")#
Time difference of -3604 secs`

Comment: Hi, Akrun, You are right that my question was about two POSIXct variables. I got in the habit of subtracting because I often manipulate the data in naive format (clock library) to deal with subtracting and adding time variables in a time zone. The challenge with naive format is that some operations won't work with it, so I end up switching back to POSIXct in those cases.

Comment: It may be better to post questions with more clarity - ie. with reproducible example and expected output.  Otherwise, it can be confusing to readers with the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it chose *minutes* instead of *seconds* is that the default is to use a "suitable" set; from [`?difftime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html) (which is used for `time1 - time2`):

```
     If 'units = "auto"', a suitable set of units is chosen, the
     largest possible (excluding '"weeks"') in which all the absolute
     differences are greater than one.
```

If you already have a vector `vec` of time differences, then you can force the units in a couple of ways.

```r
vec <- Sys.time() - (Sys.time() - 8888)
vec
# Time difference of 2.468889 hours
```

1. If you want to preserve the `difftime` attribute (and therefore how it prints/formats), you can do

   ```r
   units(vec)
   # [1] "hours"
   units(vec) <- "secs"
   vec
   # Time difference of 8888 secs
   ```

   or *inline* (functional, does not change `vec`):

   ```r
   `units<-`(vec, "secs")
   # Time difference of 8888 secs
   vec
   # Time difference of 2.468889 hours
   ```
2. If you don't need to preserve the `difftime` attribute, then you can just do

   ```r
   as.numeric(vec, units = "secs")
   # [1] 8888
   ```

This should work regardless of being in a `mutate` or a grouped `mutate` or whatever.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. I didn't realize that when subtracting I could also set the units.

Comment: Just learned that this still won't work for me in naive time, specifically. It says in response to the command "units(vec)" :  Error in UseMethod("units") : 
  no applicable method for 'units' applied to an object of class "c('clock_duration', 'clock_rcrd', 'vctrs_rcrd', 'vctrs_vctr')" I think for naive time, it only gives the answer in seconds. It doesn't give an error for the subtraction, just ignores the "unit" in the subtraction command.

Comment: What do you mean "naive time"? That is not familiar to me.

Comment: Naive time is from the "clock" library: https://clock.r-lib.org/reference/index.html  . Since I'm working with longitudinal data and manipulating and aggregating those dates and times, it allows me not to worry until the end of the processing about ambiguous times (the possibility of two times at 1:30 am on day light savings). If I use time in POSIXct format, it won't alert me when this occurs.

Comment: Well, sorry, your question mentioned `POSIXct` and didn't get into the `clock`/naive part. I don't use that package, so I can't offer much. However, it exports `duration_seconds`, have you tried that function?

Comment: Yeah, sorry! I didn't realize that my question was *actually* about both variable types. :) In reality, it may even be an even different question because the reason I was switching to POSIXct was to get around another issue with naive time. Haha! Exchange one problem for another!